# Filters are like servlets. There exists many servlet container.Do filters take the role in servlet container only?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I read everytime Filters are like servlets. Resin is a servlet container. Is there exist any filter container to initialize filters or does it take the role in servlet container only. Can anybody elaborate how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Servlets are components that handle an HTTP request/response cycle
- Filters are components that *intercept* HTTP requests and response before/after they reach the target servlet
- Servlet containers make sure the two points above work - i.e. they instantiate servlets and filters and "give" them the requests/responses

Comment: And Filters are *part* of Servlet API. Note the package name http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like Filter container, it is included in servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

Java Servlet Filters allow you to "layer on" additional behavior in front of a Servlet, JSP page, or even static resources like css, js, and image files.

The classic example of Filter use is Authorization:  checking to ensure the user is authorized to view the specified resource.

Some observations:

- A Filter can do work before the specified resource (servlet, etc.), after, or both
- Multiple Filters may be applied to the same resource